# Second loop is getting executed first

Tags: java, swing, loops

`tf` is a `JTextField`.

Expected flow of execution:

1. The control is not supposed to move out of the `first loop` until something is entered in the `JTextField` named `tf` .
2. Second `while loop` should only run after the control moves out of the first one.

   ```
   while(true)
   {
       if((!tf.getText().equals("")))
       {
   p.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
      String name=tf.getText();
      System.out.println("Hello "+name+",\nWelcome to Guess the number Game");
   }
   });
   break;

   }
       else if (tf.getText().equals(""))
       {
            p.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                        p.setSelected(false);
                   }
               });
            continue;
       }
   } //while end
   while(true)
   {   st="game on";
       System.out.println(st);
       if(!st.equals(""))
       {
       gamer3 game1=new gamer3();
       Thread nt =new Thread(game1);
       nt.start();

       break;
   }
   ```

Problems:

- Second `while loop` is getting executed first. `game on` got printed.
- As soon as I enter something into `tf` ,the code inside second `while loop` gets executed. Why is the control moving to second `while loop` as soon as I enter something into `tf`? Second `while loop` is not even dependent on `tf`.
- I don't even need to press `enter` after entering something into `tf`. How is the entered value being recognized before pressing `enter` ?

Main issue:

- Why is the second loop getting executed first?
- According to the general flow of control, the control has to remain in the first loop until it encounters a `break` statement. Why is this not being followed here?
- The control moves back to the previous loop when I press the start button.
- Control never enters the `else if` in first while loop.

Note:
Second while loop gets executed only after I enter something into `tf`. And as soon as I press the Start Button first while loop gets executed.[image: initial GUI]
[image: when something is entered in tf,note the console, not even pressed enter and second loop executed]
[image: After pressing start,content in first loop gets executed]

Comment: I'd be concerned about your repeatedly adding `ActionListener`s to the fields within a loop, be just compounding them. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have added the images to show what is actually happening. And in the `problems` section, I have mentioned what is not expected to happen. I wrote `System.out.println("loop 1");` in the first while loop and it actually prints `loop 1` repeatedly. Which means, the control remains in `loop 1` until something is entered in the text field.

Comment: Can't debug an image

Comment: @MadProgrammer What else would you need-other than the code and images?..I have provided the code which is actually causing a problem.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try to put a break point at the begining of the first loop to understand what's happening there?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Made the code minimal.

Comment: @TDG I used a print statement and I recognized that the control is moving out of the `first while loop` as soon as I enter something into the yellow text field without even pressing `enter`.

Comment: But not complete, compilable or verifiable

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is it compulsory to press `enter` to submit something entered in a text field?

Comment: Why don't you just disable the button when the textbox is empty and enable it when there is content? A while true loop on the non-GUI thread isn't doing you any good

Comment: @MathewsMathai It's contextual, I use a combination of `DocumentListener` and Swing `Timer` to perform "automated" functions a lot (like searching), so not it's not "compulsory", but the user might expect it

Comment: @cricket_007 I will consider that. The thing is, the text in JTextField is being submitted even if I don't press `enter` .

Comment: @MadProgrammer does it require `enter` to be pressed by default?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Again, that would depend on the context. You will need to press [Enter] if you have an `ActionListener` registered to the field in order for the listener to be notified

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay Got it. I have no action listeners linked to the text field. That is the reason why it is getting submitted automatically.

Comment: I "suspect" it's getting submitted automatically because you have an uncontrolled thread which is inspect the state of the field - Swing is not thread safe and you should not be monitoring or modify the state from outside the context of the EDT, remember, Swing (like most GUIs) is event driven

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would like to delete the post since there is no answer to it. But the comments are useful. Would you mind compressing your comments and posting as an answer? So that I could accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a runnable example, it's difficult to ascertain what an out-of-context snippet of code might or might not do

I "suspect" you have an uncontrolled thread which is inspect the state of the field which is triggering actions which you aren't prepared for - Swing is not thread safe and you should not be monitoring or modify the state from outside the context of the EDT, remember, Swing (like most GUIs) is event driven.

Normally you would use either a `DocumentListener` to get real time feedback or an `ActionListener` so you can be notified when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button (or presses another button on the UI)